# How to setup custom serenity.properties location?

Tags: java, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I would like to load custom serenity.properties from specific directory etc. src/test/resources/properties/serenity.properties via gradle

I tried to use -Dproperties parameter with absolute path to file (as it is recommended on their site) but it was not working

Answer (score 1):

You can put your Properties werever you would like but you need to remember the properties is part of the project. Therefore when you pass in your -d properties parameter it will be from the directory you are running the project from. So you would do something very simple like:

```
-Dproperties=src/test/resources/properties/serenity.properties
```

Mine is in a properties directory on the root and I modified the name so mine looks like this:

```
-Dproperties=properties/desktop.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method in your build which loads the data from properties file.

```
// Read serenity.properties
def getSerenityProperties(){

    def props = new Properties();
    def propFile = file('/path/to/directory/with/serenity.properties')
    props.load(propFile.newDataInputStream())
    return props;
}
// assign properties data to a variable
project.ext.serenity = getSerenityProperties()

// use property
serenity.xyz
serenity.pqr
```